# Trying to get property of non-object in Laravel Function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm making a function that each time I add a comment to an RMA Ticket it sends an email to the user but I'm getting `Trying to get property of non-object` when I submit the comment

Below I pasted the code from the CommentController and the Email function
if you want more information just ask and i will post what i could

I'm getting the error on this code - `$mailer->sendRmaTicketComments($comment->ticket->user, Auth::user(), $comment->ticket, $comment);`

CommentController Code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Rma;

use Auth;
use App\User;

use App\Rma\RmaTicket;
use App\Rma\RmaComments;

use App\Mailers\AppMailer;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class RmaCommentController extends Controller
{
    public function postComment(Request $request, AppMailer $mailer)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
           'comment'    => 'required',
           'user_id'    => 'required',
        ]);

        $comment = RmaComments::create([
           'rma_ticket_id'  => $request->input('ticket_id'),
           'user_id'    => $request->input('user_id'),
           'comment'    => $request->input('comment'),
        ]);

        $mailer->sendRmaTicketComments($comment->ticket->user, Auth::user(), $comment->ticket, $comment);

        return redirect()->back()->with('successPanel', 'Thank you for your message please allow up to 48 hours for a response.');
    }
}
```

Mail Function Code

```
<?php

namespace App\Mailers;

use App\Rma\RmaTicket;
use App\Rma\RmaStatus;

use App\SupportTickets\SupportTicket;
use App\SupportTickets\SupportTicketStatus;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailer;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class AppMailer
{
    protected $mailer;

    /**
     * Get the email address
     *
     * @var [type]
     */
    protected $to;

    /**
     * Set the subject for the email
     *
     * @var [type]
     */
    protected $subject;

    /**
     * Set the template for the email
     *
     * @var [type]
     */
    protected $view;

    /**
     * Set the data for the email
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $data = [];

    public function __construct(Mailer $mailer)
    {
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
    }

/**
     * Send RMA Comments/Replies to RMA Owner
     *
     * @param User      $ticketOwner
     * @param User      $user
     * @param rmaTicket $rmaTicket
     * @param Comment   $comment
     *
     * @return method delivered()
     */
    public function sendRmaTicketComments($ticketOwner, $user, RmaTicket $rmaTicket, $comment)
    {
        $this->to      = $ticketOwner->email;
        $this->subject = "RE[RMA Ticket # $rmaTicket->rma_ticket_id]";
        $this->view    = 'emails.rma.rma_comments';
        $this->data    = compact('ticketOwner', 'user', 'rmaTicket', 'comment');

        return $this->deliver();
    }
```

RmaComments Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Rma;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class RmaComments extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'rma_comments';
    protected $fillable = [
        'rma_ticket_id', 'user_id', 'comment'
    ];

    public function ticket()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(RmaTicket::class);
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

RMA Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Rma;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class RmaTicket extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'rma_tickets';
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'rma_ticket_id', 'first_name', 'last_name',
        'email', 'fax', 'company', 'marketplace_id', 'returnTypeId',
        'product_name', 'quantity', 'order_number', 'address_one',
        'address_two', 'city', 'state', 'zip_code', 'sku', 'model_number', 'comment',
        'status_id', 'rma_number', 'refund_number', 'return_tracking_number',
        'replacement_number', 'return_label'
    ];

    public function returnType()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(RmaReturnType::class);
    }

    public function marketplace()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(RmaMarketplace::class);
    }

    public function status()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(RmaStatus::class);
    }


     public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(RmaComments::class);
    }


    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line are you getting the error on?

Comment: @aynberI just updated my question

Comment: Which line are you getting error?Your error means that it can not find that property  then please check $user or RMATicket.

Comment: I'm guessing that you may need to reload your `$comment`, since it may not have the relationship when you create it. If that's not it, try dumping `$comment` and `$comment->ticket`

Comment: @AliGhasemzadeh  ok it looks like i get it from $comment->ticket

Comment: @aynber the error happens on $comment->ticket

Comment: Check https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: Okay, so either the relationship doesn't exist, or you need to reload the object.

Comment: Add relationships and reload object.

Comment: @AliGhasemzadeh  i already had the relationship i added the model code to my question

Comment: Try this above your mailer line, and below your create: `$comment = RmaComments::find($comment->id);`

Comment: @aymber I'm still getting `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: i changed some stuff around a now i get this `Type error: Argument 2 passed to App\Mailers\AppMailer::sendRmaTicketComments() must be an instance of App\Rma\RmaTicket, null given, called in C:\Users\edv3\Desktop\ui\app\Http\Controllers\Rma\RmaCommentController.php on line 31`

Comment: argument 2 used to be $user, and RmaTicket  instance was the third? Did you take it out?

Comment: And can you show your Rmaticket model

Comment: @robbyrr  Just added the RmaTicket model to the question

Comment: And if you dd($comment->ticket->user) just before $mailer->sendRmaTicketComments(....) to verify if thats the problem

Comment: @robbyrr   I just tried `dd($comment->ticket->user);` and I get `Trying to get property of non-object`  it looks like I get the error on both  `$comment->ticket->user` and `$comment->ticket`

Comment: @robbyrr  and if I try `dd($comment->ticket);` I get null

Comment: As a matter of fact i believe if you name your foreign key just ticket_id in your rma_comments table it will find the ticket.

Comment: @robbyrr it successfully dumps the $comment

Comment: i have edited my answer. Try specifying it as second argument in your belongsTo method like in the answer return $this->belongsTo(RmaTicket::class, 'rma_ticket_id');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code and since you have null if you dd($comment->ticket) i believe it's the naming of your foreign keys.

your belongsTo:

```
 public function ticket()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(RmaTicket::class);
}
```

expects an ticket_id but you named it rma_ticket_id.

You could specify a different foreign key name in the second argument in the belongTo relationship

```
public function ticket()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(RmaTicket::class, 'rma_ticket_id');
}
```

As per the docs:

> . Eloquent determines the default foreign key name by examining the name of the relationship method and suffixing the method name with _id. However, if the foreign key on the  Phone model is not user_id, you may pass a custom key name as the second argument to the  belongsTo method:

Comment: :) glad it fixed the issue

Comment: I fixed the  `$comment->ticket->user` by adding `use App\User` to the model :)